# Can EC2 manage my servers system properties dynamically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As many other systems, my system got lots of system properties from it's properties files.

I wonder if there is a way to maintain and update those properties from AWS console to my servers which are running in EC2 ?

The goal is to update 2 of my 20 servers in AWS with a certain system property to 'false' and so on.

Comment: You probably want to look into some kind of configuration management tool like Puppet, Chef, or Ansible.

Comment: @Rome_Leader im actually asking if there is a way to make it from AWS-EC2 ?

Comment: Have you looked into AWS Systems Manager?